# Quick question about ports on a web address

Tags: websocket, https, port

I got a little confused about sockets.
In an address like:

https://localhost:5000/

...where I am running a web server during development, I know that the HTTPS translates to the local port 443, so the question is, **what is the 5000 port number in that address?**

Comment: I flagged this question to be moved to [webmasters.se] because it is not a programming question that is on-topic here. Because this question already has an answer, please wait for it be moved rather than re-asking it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS **defaults** to port 443, *unless otherwise specified.* In `localhost:5000` you *are* explicitly specifying a port, so it's port 5000. Only `https://localhost` would be using port 443 implicitly.

Comment: So the https 443 port is ignored? and in the example I would be using SSL through port 5000? Is that right?

Comment: "Ignored" is a weird way of putting it. You're explicitly specifying a port, so there's no need to default to the default HTTPS port of 443. And yes, you're using HTTPS through port 5000 instead. Anything can be used through any port, simply certain services have defined default ports so you don't need to explicitly specify them every time and don't need to guess.

Comment: Thank you, deceze!

Answer (score 0):

when you request localhost:5000, the browser will go to the webserver on the localhost, but on port 5000, this means that if your webserver is setup to work on port 5000 or one of it's virtual hosts are setup to work on port 5000 you will get a response,

Read this line very carefully thrice, **the browser will go to the webserver on the localhost, but on port 5000**,
so , answer to the question **what is the 5000 port number in that address?** is that the webserver will try to find a response from port number 5000 , it will not go and find response on any other location .
read more about port numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking))
I hope it makes sense to you !
Thanks !